# Socket.io and Webscocket listen on the same server

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, websocket, socket.io

I need to share same http server between socket.io and websocket (from 'ws' package) handlers. 
Unfortunatelly, despite that they are listening to diffrent prefixes, the first is listening to /socket.io and the second to /websocket urls, for some reasons if they are running on the same server the websocket is not working properly.

I did some debugging, but it seems that the requests are properly handled by both libraries but in the end only socket.io works properly.

Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Why are you using both?

Comment: Complexity of dependencies and type of clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way sockets work in node.js is quite a bit different from the way normal requests work.  There is no routing, so rather than listening to a url, you have to listen to all sockets.  The default behavior of `socket.io` is to close any socket connections that it doesn't recognize.  To fix this, you'll need to add the flag `'destroy upgrade': false` to the options (`server` is an express server):

```
require('socket.io').listen(server, {'destroy upgrade': false, ...})
```

You'll also need to check the url when a client connects (in the code handling `/websocket`) and ignore it if it looks like it belongs to `socket.io`.  You can find the url from the client object (passed in to the on `connection` handler) as `client.upgradeReq.url`.

Comment: thanks, I figured  it out a minute ago. Where where you all day long :)

Comment: @Luman75 It's morning here.  I just put together a similar server setup, so feel free to ping me if you have more questions.

Comment: thanks again, I'm integrating sharejs over websocket and socket.io clients in one environment. I wanted to avoid listening on multiple ports.

Answer (score 0):

Ok solution is simple (unfortunately half day of debugging and now it's simple :)).

There is an option 'destroy upgrade' for upgrade requests coming from non-socketio clients. Since Websocket (module 'ws') is using the same requests some of them might be for 'ws' not for 'socket.io'. So this option should be disabled.

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(server,  { log: false, 'resource':'/socket.io'  });
io.disable('destroy upgrade')
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for 2016:

```
io.disable('destroy upgrade');
```

seems not to be available anymore.
But I succeeded by assigning the websocket module ws a path (using Express):

```
 var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server, path: '/ws' }); //do not interfere with socket.io
```

Of course the client has the same path ws://theserver.com/ws

I did not have to alter the socket.io side at all.